# Why isn't my Arduino Nano Every recognized as a Nano Every and why won't it upload sketch?

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, uploading

I have a genuine Arduino Nano Every board that isn't showing up quite right.  I actually have 2 hooked up to the computer on different ports and one of them, when I click on 'Port' shows as:

```
COM12 (Arduino Nano Every)
```

But the other one just shows up as:

```
COM18
```

The COM18 device used to have (Arduino Nano Every), but doesn't anymore.  The other problem I have is that when I try to upload a sketch to the device, it compiles and gets to uploading and then has a bunch of errors:

```
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

I've tried changing the selection on "Registers emulation:" between ATMEGO328 and None (ATMEGA4809) but I get the same errors whenever I try to upload a sketch.  Is my Every bricked?  Or is there some way to revive it?

I'm not sure why this happened.  I was able to upload sketches before, and have barely even used this device.

Does somebody have any ideas on how to get this working again, or should I just throw it away and get another one?

Comment: the USB chip on Nano Every is a SAMD11 with Arduino firmware. you could try to flash the firmware. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/NANOEvery#firmware-for-samd11d14a

Comment: Your programmer chip is bricked. Lol

Comment: I'm not the one who voted down, but you might show some effort, like trying to restore the bootloader. Both symptoms are clear: The Arduino does not work as the expected USB device any more. You might need to use another programmer (another Arduino for example) to access it.

Comment: Don't worry about the down-vote. If you got 20 you might worry. :)

Comment: Encountered this on linux, solved by selecting the tty/ACM0 port